# Eclipse Modeling Framework: Linking an alternative view to the model

Tags: eclipse, jface, eclipse-emf

I have an ECore model I exploit to automatically generate the model source and JFace edit package. I am trying to develop an alternative view for contents of that model, basically a graph view based on JFreeChart. I have managed to create a JFreeChart based view plugin. Now I need to link the view with the model. How can I do that? I would like to edit the model with the TreeBased editor and see the effects of such editing in the graph view. Is that possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have managed to do that following the  Zoltán suggestions. Anyway I admit I would have preferred a more structured answer, and that is why I am answering my own question with a brief summary of the solution.

basically the idea is that a view plugin implements the ViewPart interface. Because of this it can actually invoke the following methods

```
getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService()
```

in order to get the workbench selection service. You can therefore invoke the SelectionService method

```
addSelectionListener(ISelectionListener listener)
```

passing as parameter your own ISelectionListener which can be the same ViewPart you are implementing. You just have to implement the ISelectionListener interface and thus provide an implementation of the selectionChanged method

```
public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart sourcepart, ISelection selection)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open your Graphbased-View ask for the IFile of the current opened editor. After you got the file, you can load the model (see the generated Editor how to load the Model from the underlying resource) attach a IResourceChangeListener to get a notification, if the underlying IFile of your EMF Model changed.
After a notification you can reload the model from your file  and show the model in your view.

In addition you have to register a PartListener to get a notification if the user brings another emf-editor to top or he closes the editor (you also have to unload (on close) or refresh (another editor with your emf-model was brought to top).

Comment: Hmm... how will live changes to the ecore model be reflected in the chart this way? Isn't it better to use the selection service to get the current selected `EModelElement`, get the model root - `EPackage` -, adda content adapter if not present, and then update the chart?

Comment: If you want to visualize live-updates, yes. With the Resource-Listener the diagram will be only refreshed if you save the editor. But listening directly at the model has other drawbacks (e.g. if the user wants to use an alternative Model-Viewer). Selection-Service is not useful, what if I select an element in my Package-Viewer while the editor and the view remain open? What to use depends on the requirements and also on the model (e.g. has the model cross-references to other models, etc.)

Comment: I agree. It depends on requirements. When I use the selection listener, I often test of the current selection owner to only update the view of relevant changes...

Comment: I actually open the file from the default editor. I just would like to provide a further view to its contents. My question is How can I get a reference to my models / or register my view as a listener to its changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, as the generated EMF code provides a notification layer: use EObject.eAdapters to add a new adapter, that is notified if the model is changed.

```
    object.eAdapters().add(new Adapter() {

        public void setTarget(Notifier newTarget) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void notifyChanged(Notification notification) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public boolean isAdapterForType(Object type) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public Notifier getTarget() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: to what object shall I add the Adapter? I guess the model but how can i get a reference to it from the view plugin? (thank you)

Comment: As Tom Seidel wrote in the other answer, you could use a workbench listener to reply to opening of editors, and then get their opened files; you could also listen to the workbench selection API, and get a reference to the model that way. In both ways, get the root element of the models, and use the following: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/Recipes#Recipe:_Use_EContentAdapter_to_receive_notifications_from_a_whole_containment_tree

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. I actually do not know how to add such selection listener. I mean i have imported the ModelPackage in my view plugin and it seems i can get an instance of it since it is a Singleton. However it seems it just allow me to dive into the meta-model not the model.

Comment: You cannot open instance models using the ModelPackage. You can create your own using the ModelFactory class; you can open one using the Resource/ResourceSet API; or you can use the Platform Selection API (independent of EMF) to get the selected object from the current editor.

Comment: I see. But how should I use the Selection API? what observer should I register to what object?

Comment: Look at the following article for details: http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html

Comment: I am having trouble in using JFace since I do not want to use default viewers but actually implementing a new one. I am wondering whether to exploit JFace Data Binding but, once again, I do need to have at least the root object of my model. What do you mean with Resource/ResourceSet API, I guess that is what I really need. Could you pleas succest me a tutorial about this topic?

Comment: EMF models are stored inside Resources/ResourceSets. If you get a model element, you can obtain its container resource by calling EObject.eResource() - and the root content element of this resource should be the root of the model, that might be needed for adding an EMF adapter. But I see, using the Workbench Selection API was enough for your needs.